# Unwrapping Specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This my snpiset code

```
<pre id='code'>
   <ol>
     <li class='L1'><span>helo</span></li>
     <li class='L2'><span>Hai</span></li>
     <li class='L3'>
       <span>yes</span>
       <div class='dx'></div>
       <div class='dy'></div>
     </li>
   </ol>
</pre>
<script>
var pTags = $("ol > li > .dx");
    pTags.unwrap();
</script>
```

the class of li is auto generated. I want to make the result like this

```
<pre id='code'>
  <ol>
     <li class='L1'><span>helo</span></li>
     <li class='L2'><span>Hai</span></li>
    <li class='L3'><span>yes</span></li>
  </ol>
  <div class='dx'></div>
  <div class='dy'></div>
</pre>
```

but my code doesnt give me the result like above. please help me

Comment: what is `<div ='dx'></div>` and `<div ='dy'></div>`?  are they classes or id's?

Comment: it class, sorry im typo :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
$('#code div').appendTo('#code');
```

which will move the div's out as the last children of the `<pre>` element

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b3YAr/)